# Qual o significado específico de «desconfiar de» + oração subordinada?

Tags: sintaxe, orações-subordinadas, semântica, regência-verbal

1. Entendo que o verbo "desconfiar" pode ser usado com oração subordinada substantiva objetiva direta - como em "**Desconfio que Maria tenha comparecido ao evento**", em que o locutor, não tendo certeza do comparecimento ou não, enfatiza a possibilidade de Maria ter sim comparecido ao evento.
2. O verbo "desconfiar" também pode ser usado com objeto indireto - como em
   "**Desconfio de José**", em que o locutor, não tendo certeza se José merece confiança, enfatiza a possibilidade de José não merecer confiança.

Gostaria de saber se é aceito e qual o significado do uso de "desconfiar" com oração subordinada substantiva objetiva indireta - como em "**Desconfio *de* que Maria tenha comparecido ao evento**".

À primeira vista, parece-se com o uso em (1) e significaria que o locutor, não tendo certeza do comparecimento ou não, enfatiza a possibilidade de Maria ter *sim* comparecido ao evento.
No entanto, em análise mais detalhada, nota-se que se usa nesta frase sintaxe semelhante à de (2), sendo que o objeto indireto foi substituído por oração subordinada. Nesse caso, significaria que o locutor enfatiza a possibilidade da afirmação "Maria compareceu ao evento" não merecer confiança, ou seja, enfatizaria a possibilidade de Maria *não* ter comparecido ao evento.

Comment: @ANeves, obrigado pelas melhorias.

Comment: toliveira, tentei melhorar a clareza da pergunta - espero que as edições te agradem.

Comment: ah, agradaram :)

Comment: Notei que usaste "sentença", que em Portugal [não é sinónimo de frase](https://dicionario.priberam.org/senten%C3%A7a) e significa apenas «decisões de juizes». Se quiseres respostas apenas sobre português do Brasil, podes usar a tag "português-brasileiro".

Comment: @ANeves, substituí "sentença" por "frase", pois me interesso também pelo português de Portugal. Agradeço o aviso.

Answer (score 3):

Tem o significado de **conjecturar**, (ou seja, *1*) quer com, quer sem a preposição "de".

De acordo com o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/desconfiar):

> 2. Conjeturar desfavoravelmente; suspeitar de algo (fato, acontecimento, ação etc.) tido como improvável [tdr. : *Desconfio de que não saiba a verdade.*] [td. : *Desconfio que não saiba a verdade.*]

E também no dicionário da [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/desconfiar), entre outros.

Em relação à definição do Aulete eu acrescentaria que a conjectura não necessariamente deve ser desfavorável. Uma frase com "Eu desconfio de que ela gosta de você." é perfeitamente válida.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, mas nāo parece consistente. Na primeira frase, afirma que tem o significado de (1). O trecho retirado do Aulete dá a entender que tem o significado de (2). Por fim, acrescenta que pode ser (1) novamente. Posso concluir que considera tanto (1) quanto (2) como significados possíveis?

Comment: Oi @toliveira Não, vejo o significado (1) como sendo melhor aplicável, até porque o exemplo do Aulete é claro em apontar que a ausência do "de" não alteraria o significado da frase. Entendo que o significado (2) é sinônimo de "não confiar" - o exemplo na questão original, "Desconfio de José", seria equivalente a "Não confio no José" (embora, claro, um contexto poderia dar o significado (1) : "Desconfio de [que seja o] José").